# Example of Mule Sharepoint connector to download a document

Tags: mule, sharepoint-2013

Does anyone have an example of how to use the Mule Sharepoint connector to download a document? I suspect this is done using the *Query* operation. I'm not sure what should go in the queryXML element though. Any pointers will be welcome - perhaps there is an easier operation.

I have successfully implemented Sharepoint's *Copy items into items* operation, to upload docs - now want to retrieve them.

I'm using Mule 3.5 with Sharepoint 2013 Foundation (so no CMIS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is simply, use get-file-as-stream operation.